# RecyclerView - items get recycled when dragging

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have `RecyclerView` which is `HORIZONTAL`. Width of each item in it nearly equals the total width of recycler. Only up to 3 `ViewHolders` are visible.

Here's some mockup for better understanding of how the result looks.

[image]

I want to add ability to reposition cards in my `RecyclerView` so I created `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` and attached it to `RecyclerView`.

Once I longpress on any card I'm able to drag it to the left and right. When I move it near the screen edge `RecyclerView` automatically starts to scroll and then my view disappears.

From what I was able to find out I guess that it simply will get recycled - `ItemTouchHelper#clearView(RecyclerView, RecyclerView$ViewHolder)` is called and it originates from `RecyclerView#removeDetachedView(View)`.

Is there any was I can bypass this behaviour?

```
ItemTouchHelper.Callback drag = new ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

        @Override
        public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END | ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
            return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            int oldPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            int newPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), String.format("View moved from %d to %d", oldPosition, newPosition));

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            // Not applicable
        }
    };

mView.recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
mView.recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter());

ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(drag);
touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mView.recycler);
```

[image: Stack from debugger when View disappears]

Comment: share your code.

Comment: I hava met the same problem, once the item is recycled, clearView() will be invoked but I don't hope that happen, it seems that if I don’t call notifyItemMoved
() in onMove() method this will happen, have you find any method to solve this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` when you start dragging try to set

```
viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false)
```

then when you end your dragging

```
viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(true)
```

Comment: so have you tried to override clearView or removeDetachedView?

Comment: ClearView is just a callback caused by removeDetachedView. Rewriting it will not help. The second option you suggest means that I should rewrite RecyclerView's layout methods which is imho way too dangerous.

Comment: yeah it could be dangerous, but you could try to act as: if (! removing current touched view) super.removeDetachedView() . it's just an idea